# Editing buildout.cfg in Plone from a browser

Tags: content-management-system, plone, buildout, diazo

I am editing a website using the Plone 4 CMS. The Plone instance I am currently using is hosted by a server to which I don't have access (i.e. I can't FTP this server and edit PHP files).

Although I don't own the server which is hosting this website, I would like to access the `buildout.cfg` file. Is there a way to edit this file by just logging in on my Plone website, or do I need to have the credentials to manipulate the whole instance of the site with FTP?

When I log in, I can go to a page called *Site Setup* (screenshot provided). Can I perhaps solve my problem from this page?

[image: Screenshot of the "Site Setup" page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The `buildout.cfg` file is used for installing / building your application. So, when you are in Site setup you already are using the running application you want to reconfigure.

You will edit your `buildout.cfg` then you will run `./bin/develop rb` to rebuild it, then you will (re)start the instance of your application. This is when, for example, you will see new add-ons available for activating them from Site setup / Add-ons (the add-ons you added in eggs / zcml / versions sections of your buildout.cfg).

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically it's possible, the code-example below shows a prototype using a  browser-view, which when called:

- Reads the content of a given page
- Writes the content to the buildout-config
- Updates the instance

Practically:

- You'd need to have access to the file-system, to install an add-on with the browser-view beforehand.
- One would ***never want to do this in production***, because if errors occur you
  cannot do much about it then.

---

```
import os
from Products.Five.browser import BrowserView


class View(BrowserView):

    def __call__(self):

        # Let's assume these paths exist:
        instance_path = '/path/to/instance'
        buildout_config_path = instance_path + 'buildout.cfg'
        page_path_in_site = 'front-page'

        # Read buildout-config of page in site:
        page = self.context[page_path_in_site]
        config_content = page.getText()

        # Write buildout-config to filesystem:
        with open(buildout_config_path, 'w') as fil:
            fil.write(page.getText())

        # Run buildout, so changes in config take effect:
        os.system(instance_path + 'buildout')

        # Restart server, so python- and zcml-files get
        # (re-)compiled, respectively loaded:
        os.system(instance_path + 'bin/instance restart')
```